# Using Mongoose to query an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got a MongoDB database collection called Dealers structured a bit like this:

```
{
 ... dealer info goes here like address etc,
"user_logins": [
               {
                  "Username": "something",
                  ... other stuff
               }
               ]
},{
... next dealer etc...
```

I'm using Mongoose to try and query on the user_logins.Username using this:

Mongoose model

```
const myTest = mongoose.Schema({
      Username: {
          type: "String",
          required: true
          }
      }, { collection: "Dealers" })
module.exports = mongoose.model("Dealer", myTest);
```

The query

```
Dealer.find({'user_logins.Username' : 'something'}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
            console.log(err);
    } else {
            res.json(result);
    }
});
```

All the Username's are distinct. But instead of returning the one matching document, it seems to be returning the whole Dealers collection.

I followed this example.

https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/use-mongoose-to-find-in-an-array-of-objects-1206

What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks.

EDIT: It seems fine if I try to find something on the root level. EG. Company name, address etc. But if I try to query an imbedded array of objects, that's when it pulls the whole collection. I don't get it.

Comment: Seems to be working here. https://mongoplayground.net/p/0AKHcz4a1Am

Comment: Yeah. You're right. I must have missed something.

Comment: But saying that, your example is using Mongosh, not Mongoose.

Comment: Can you share one complete dealer document in the question

Comment: Not really. It's pretty big and some of the information is business sensitive. Sorry.

Comment: Is the above mongoose schema is the exact schema, that you have, or it's truncated as well.

Comment: You forgotten to close one more ```}``` at the end of the schema function in mongoose model, maybe that's the reason

Comment: @Shashank KR Sorry. That was a typo. Corrected now.

Comment: @Charchit Kapoor The schema is as it reads. IE. Not truncated.

Comment: New information. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.
My model was wrong. It needed to reflect the actual structure of my data, which does kind of make sense.

This worked:

```
const myTest = mongoose.Schema({
  user_logins: [{
     Username: {
      type: "String",
      required: true
      }
  }]
}, { collection: "Dealers" })
module.exports = mongoose.model("Dealer", myTest);
```